# Как в $_REQUEST подставить значение отмеченной радиокнопки

Tags: php, html, requests, radio

Есть форма, в которой 3 input radio, есть     `file_get_contents`    в котором     `$_REQUEST`    принимает значения из радиокнопок, но мне нужно что бы принималось значение только из 1 радиокнопки. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, уже день гуглю и никак.
Спасибо.

```html
<?php $homepage = file_get_contents($_REQUEST["amount"] * 100)  ?>


<div class="form-check">
                <input name="amount" class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="flexRadioDefault1" value="<?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 3?>">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                    3% от заказа <?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 3?> (рублей).
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input name="amount" class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="flexRadioDefault2" value="<?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 5 ?>">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                    5% от заказа <?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 5 ?> (рублей).
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input name="amount" class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="flexRadioDefault2"  value="<?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 7 ?>">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                    7% от заказа <?= $_GET["sum"] / 100 * 7 ?> (рублей).
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: "но мне нужно что бы принималось значение только из 1 радиокнопки." --- в POST в текущем случае прилетит только одно значение - то, которое выбрано

Comment: `$_GET["amount"]` --- так нельзя?

Comment: Прилетает почему то все значения.

Comment: Только, если они все не отмечены

Comment: нет, отмечаю 1 ток

Comment: Да, походу кэш был. И вправду с $_POST прилетает 1 значение, почему с $_REQUEST не так?))

Comment: ты нажимаешь submit у формы? или как отправляешь запрос?  `var_dump($_POST["amount"])`

Comment: "походу кэш был" --- ясн. можно закрывать))

Comment: Нет, оказывается в другом проблема была еще. Если не один инпут не выбирается, то они передаются все. Подскажите, как написать условие что бы при клике быбиралось какое то значение))

Comment: выбери по дефолту одно из значений и не парься. Либо если count > 1 - не обрабатывать amount